# google sheets - changing a cell text based on another cell which has a date of my choosing

Tags: arrays, excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column A1:A100 which all cells are a list of the days of the month.
one the other column B1:B100 I want to say which day of the week the text on A column is.

tried this:

```
=IF(A2="01/04/2021"; "thursday"; "")
```

cant make it work for more 29 options

I need some help here

Have a nice weekend

Answer (score 3):

Try the [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en) function and wrap it in the [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) function:

```
=TEXT(WEEKDAY("01/04/2021", 1), "dddd")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I couldnt make it work but with the tip you got me I searched a little more and I did it this way:

=CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(A6; 1); "sunday"; "monday"; "tuesday"; "wednesday"; "thursday"; "friday"; "saturday")

Comment: Adam your formula is very good. @G66 You cannot make it work because you have other locale. You must use `=TEXT(WEEKDAY(A6; 1); "dddd")`